# Работа с платежными системами на PHP

Tags: php, webmoney

Не могли бы вы подсказать мне PHP-расширения, которые могут работать с системой WebMoney, например. Или еще, как вариант, это Яндекс.Деньги и PayPol, но лучше WebMoney, так как эту систему использует подавляющее большинство.

Спасибо...

Comment: https://merchant.webmoney.ru/conf/default.asp

Comment: http://clubs.ya.ru/moneyapi/replies.xml?item_no=781

Comment: o.O вообще то такие "расширения" а точнее обычно куски кода дают платёжные системы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю Вам использовать готовые агрегаторы, типа робокассы.
А так каждая платежная система дает свой код работы, к примеру, мерчант вебмани можно сделать по этому [официальному мануалу](https://wiki.webmoney.ru/wiki/show/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0+WebMoney+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B0)

Comment: Благодарю)